# configure: error: --with-ssl was given, but OpenSSL wasn't found

Tags: openssl, linux-mint, yarp

I am trying to install a software named YARP - Python bindings on Linux Mint Olivia, this requires OpenSSL to be installed, I followed these instructions to install OpenSSL 1.0.1g:
http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation

YARP configuration fails:

```
configure: error: in `/home/osama/robotpkg/pkgtools/tnftp/work.osama-Inspiron-N5010/tnftp-20130505':
| configure: error: --with-ssl was given, but OpenSSL wasn't found
| See `config.log' for more details
```

when I type `openssl version` command, I get the following result:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012)
```

I noticed that the `OpenSSL 1.0.1g` is which I installed whereas the `Library: OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012` is that comes pre-installed with Linux, may this be the problem?

Any advice?

Comment: Please provide the OpenSSL and location you are trying to use; and the commands used during YARP configure.

Comment: The output of 'which openssl' yields '/usr/local/bin/openssl', I also uninstalled the OpenSSL entirely and reinstalled again, now the output of 'openssl version' yields 'OpenSSL 1.1.0-dev xx XXX xxxx'.
I don't know what commands are used during Yarp-python installation, I just issue command 'make update' in [robotpkg](http://robotpkg.openrobots.org) and I don't know what it does after that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when installing CoovaChilli with --with-openssl. Though I don't know why since OpenSSL was already installed. But a

> yum install openssl openssl-devel

seems to have fixed it and I was able to *./configure* it without any errors.